# Getting error while adding icloud in a app having core data

Tags: iphone, core-data, icloud

This is the debugger output:

> -[NSFileManager URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:]: An error occurred while getting ubiquity container URL: Error
>   Domain=LibrarianErrorDomain Code=11 "The operation couldn’t be
>   completed. (LibrarianErrorDomain error 11 - The requested container
>   identifier is not permitted by the client's
>   com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers entitlement.)"
>   UserInfo=0x28a970 {NSDescription=The requested container identifier is
>   not permitted by the client's
>   com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers entitlement.}

Setting the app identifier as `com.companyname`

Comment: please format your code using the appropriate syntax. However, it seems that you did not set up properly the iCloud entitlement certificate.

Comment: it just the console output showing error message. My code sign entitlement is com.name and icloud entitlement is com.name.Appname, does it making this error to show up

Comment: did you already check the section in your application target ? Right at the bottom check if your entitlements settings correspond to the entitlements in developer portal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This tutorial helped me solve this error: https://goddess-gate.com/dc2/index.php/post/452

(Be careful with Team-ID and APp-Id , I confused them too in the course of setting up my project)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by    specifying my Team Id in the beginning of my  Application Bundle Identifier.

here is an example

```
 NSURL *ubiq=[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:@"G5ykslsdl.com.dribblee.iCloudDemo"];
```